# [three.js]blender export animations

Tags: animation, export, three.js, blender

## What I am trying to do?

- create object with door in blender
- create animation "open" and "close" (reversed animation) for the door
- export the model + animation
- load the model + animation in three.js
- play animation "open" or "close" just by using their names

## Where I am at?

I created a blender project which you can get [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/255893/testdoor.blend)
In that project I managed to create an action "open" and to export it through three.js exporter

## What is my problem?

I tried to create a second action "close", but I can't find a way to export both.

So my questions are, is it possible to have an action and its reverse stored in blender and exporter for three.js?
Am I going the wrong way? Is there a better solution to do that?

[here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/255893/testdoor.js) is the exported js file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems at the moment you can't have a single export with multiple animations. See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/2899.